# Creating new entities and changing an entity in prePersist

Tags: doctrine-orm

in a sense I would like to transfer my old question [Flushing in postPersist possible or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52460477/flushing-in-postpersist-possible-or-not) to the `prePersist`event.

Suppose the following example

```
class Entity {

    /** @PrePersist */
    public function doStuffOnPrePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $this->value = 'changed from prePersist callback!';
        $other  = new OtherEntity();

        $args->getEntityManager()->persist($other);
    }
}
```

called like

```
$entity = new Entity();
$entity->value = "unchanged";
$em->persist($entity);
$em->flush();
```

I have 2 fundamental questions:

### - Will the `value` written to db be "unchanged" or "Changed from..."?

### - Will the `OtherEntity` be written to DB?

Assuming both questions are answered with yes, let me extend my question:

Both, `Entity` and `OtherEntity` have an Autogenerated id field and `OtherEntity` has a reference (ManyToOne) to `Entity`:

```
class Entity {
    /* 
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    /** @PrePersist */
    public function doStuffOnPrePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $this->value = 'changed from prePersist callback!';
        $other  = new OtherEntity();
        $other->father = $this;    // <-------------
        $args->getEntityManager()->persist($other);
    }
}
```

### Will this work, too?

Comment: Instead of writing down this question with all of this code, why did you not simply try it, as you've written the code anyway? Are you using a debugger, like [xdebug](https://xdebug.org/) to step through your code and see what happens?

Comment: I of course do have implemented all this. However, I could nowhere find definite answers to my questions and want to make sure I am using this feature as intended. Otherwise a new version release in the future might break my logic.

Comment: Ah right, then I misunderstood. My apologies. It would then seem you need [these docs](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/events.html), the Event System of Doctrine. If you're using Doctrine, you could take [this repo](https://github.com/salesupply/zf-doctrine-encrypt-module) which I wrote as an example, as it hooks into pre-/post Flush/Persist. [Specifically this file at this point](https://github.com/salesupply/zf-doctrine-encrypt-module/blob/cbc01e8adbc1213db888cea5e1da94fe50747489/src/Subscriber/DoctrineEncryptSubscriber.php#L178)

Comment: If you need more, let me know and I'll try to work up an example for you